# Error when trying to Marshall postman collection JSON to java request object, why?

Tags: java, arraylist, postman, marshalling

I'm trying to take a postman collection as a JSON input and Marshall it to a request Java object. Below is my input and respective java object along with the error.

```
{"item": [
{
  "name": "name1",
  "item": [
    {
      "name": "name2",
      "event": [
        {
          "listen": "test",
          "script": {
            "exec": [
              "irrelevant data",
              "irrelevant data"
            ],
            "type": "text/javascript",
            "id": "1234"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

Java Objects:

```
public class Request {
    private List<Item> item;
}

public class Item {
    private String name;
    private List<Event> event;
    private List<Item> item;
}
```

Error:

> JSON decoding error: Cannot deserialize instance of Item out of
> START_ARRAY token nested exception is
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException

If I get rid of the List item from the Item class the request goes through but I only obtain the first item which is name1, and that's all I get. I tried making the item class have an array Item[] item and just a single Item 'Item item' as well but all produce the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Because the class `Item` cannot have a field `List<Item>`, it will make recursion, I guess. You can do like this.

```
public class Request {
    private List<Item> item;
}

public class Item {
    private String name;
    @JsonProperty("item")
    private List<NestedItem> nestedItem;
}

public class NestedItem {
    private String name;
    private List<Event> event;
}
```